# Does Rakinishu's Blade have a special purpose?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I found Rakinishu's blade at an event in act II, does it  have any purpose, or is it just a sort of Easter egg / in joke?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is used for an **achievement** and in the other hand it is **Easter egg**.

```
Achievement: "Bashanishu - Hurt Bashiok using Rakanishu’s Blade."
```

[Rakanishu's blade](http://www.d3lexicon.com/item/rakanishus-blade) is a easter egg from diablo 2 monster [Rakanishu](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Rakanishu).

[Bashiok](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/bashiok-spotted-in-the-wild) is a monster created after an blizzard employee [Bashiok](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/a-bashiok-achievement).

Answer (score 2):

There is no known use of it yet, other than earning the **Bashinishu** achievement.

For this achievement, simply hit Bashiok with Rakinishu's Blade.

There is a banner accent as a reward for this achievement.