# Does Griswold's Worn Edge have special use?

Tags: diablo-iii

[The ingredients for the Herding Staff and the Herding Staff itself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67096/23580) all have flavour text and a specific purpose. Rakanishu's blade is a blade gained from the Shrine of Rakanishu event in the Dahlgur Oasis and is [used for the achievement Bashanishu](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/67800/23580) for which you must hurt Bashiok using Rakanishu's Blade.

Is there any special purpose to Griswold's Worn Edge which can be found in the Old Ruins in Griswold's smithy or is it simply a reference to Griswold the blacksmith from Diablo?

[image: This weapon is quite poor]

Comment: Griswold's Masterpiece has flavor text because all legendaries have flavor text.

Comment: @RavenDreamer and Griswold's Word Edge or Rakanishu's Blade which are not legendary? Do you have an explanation for those? The question is still valid, but part of the answer might be that Griswold's Masterpiece doesn't have a special purpose.

Comment: No clue. But your question should limit itself to Griswold's Worn Edge, because the flavor text on the other items make sense.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Fine. Whatever. But if Griswold's Masterpiece does have a special purpose, you'll owe me an apology.

Comment: I'd much rather owe you than have a question for every legendary on the site asking, "does *this* legendary item have a special purpose?" ;)

Comment: Any way to repair the 'worn' edge of this blade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three types of items with flavor text:

Legendaries and other Uniques, "Special" items like Herding Staff components, and Easter egg items.

In your case you have an "easter egg" item similar to this:

[image]

is an easter egg reference to the Borderlands boss Nine-Toes, who drops the gun "The Clipper"