# Why does this item have a legend? Are there others like it?

Tags: diablo-iii

[image: Tooltip for the Splintered Oar, a Magic Two-Handed Sword, with the legend: "From Kingsport to Kurast we sail. From Lut Gholein to Skovos we roam. When the wind's not blowing, we'll row our damned way home!" - The Sea Trader's Song]

Is this some kind of special item?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Griswold's Worn Edge have special use?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67993/does-griswolds-worn-edge-have-special-use)

Comment: I think it's a reference to Meshif from Act II (Lut Gholein) of D2.

Comment: @Krazer it may well be

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a **Unique Item**. **Unique items** are items that have a unique model, name, and a piece of lore at the bottom of their item description. They also have more constrained affixes(though there is still some variation). A **unique item** is different from a legendary item, in that not all unique items are legendary, but all legendary items are unique, other than that, they are incredibly similar aside from the number of affixes.

For whatever reason, The Diablo 3 Item Database does not list these items, perhaps because they are intended to be an easter egg of some sort(one item, The Clipper, is a reference to Borderlands), or because they have not completed the database yet.

[Information on this item from the unofficial item database, which erroneously lists it as legendary](http://d3db.com/item/i/splintered-oar)

Comment: No, it is **not** a Legendary weapon. Legendary Weapons have their names in *Orange*, and have generally have more than two affixes.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Check the comments on the item page. Blizzard messed up somewhere along the way because this is clearly a legendary weapon that for some reason drops as a magic weapon. It is the same in all respects but that.

Comment: I'm actually more inclined to believe that's an error or a quirk of the way D3DB's database is coded. You'll find if you look at Blizzards official item database, that items like the Splintered Oar, Griswold's Worn Edge, and Rakanishu's Blade don't show up at all. This is because they don't really 'fit in' to the classification scheme of other items in the game. They are 'special' in that they are named, but they are *not* legendary, which carries certain criteria with respect to item budget that these items do not meet.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Splintered Oar can certainly be found on D3DB, and it is listed as a Legendary weapon. This leads me to believe the game is bugged, not the database. I have, however, updated my answer to reflect this quirk.

Comment: D3DB is **not** Blizzards official item database. The Splintered Oar [does not appear in the official Game Guide site,](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sword-2h/) nor do the other items mentioned. Like I said, I believe these items show up as Legendary on D3DB as a quirk of the way D3DB's database handles items, not because they are *intended* to be legendary and simply bugged in the game.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I figured it was, simply due to the comprehensive nature of it. Regardless, I'm still erring on the side of this being a game bug, as this meets literally every criterion for being  a legendary other than it dropping as a magic item.

Comment: @Mr.November If it were a legendary, it would have more than two modifiers on it. I found 3 low level legendary weapons that only had 4 modifiers on them. Every other one had more (including some lower level weapons that had more).

Answer (score 5):

The item mentioned above is a 'unique' item, but is only of magic rarity. It has some flavour text but there are many non-legendary items in the game that do. The flavour text is intended to aid immersion, and to provide you some back story on what that item means within the game world.

Here is a link to the Diablo 3 US forums with lists of other items of similar rarity with flavour text;

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5151722071

Other examples;

- Griswold's Worn Edge
- Rakanishu's Blade
- Wirt's Original Leg
- The Clipper
- Spectrum

While these may not appear in the official Diablo 3 item database, it's worth noting that Rakanishu's Blade in particular is specifically required for one of the challenge achievements (Bashanishu).

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a legendary.

Yes there are others like it.  My favorite is Wirt's Original Leg.

Blizzard just has a really good sense of humor and likes to entertain their fans.  They brought back a lot of the items from D2 and D1.  Some of them are meant as jokes and some are just for nostalgia.  My buddy didn't stop laughing for 5 minutes when he saw Obsidian ring of the Zodiac was made a legendary in this game.