# What's the most efficient way to farm recipes?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do recipes drop in diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72652/where-do-recipes-drop-in-diablo-3)

Are they counted as a 'magic' drop (in which case stacking MF and killing elites would work), or are they a completely separate kind of drop (in which case killing large numbers of non-elite mobs would work best).