# Which is the earliest act/area where Jeweler design drops?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do recipes drop in Diablo 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72652/where-do-recipes-drop-in-diablo-3)

I am having a hard enough time playing Inferno in Diablo 3.

The only reason I am playing through and through is to find the Jeweler's design. I am getting tired of it and I'd like to know if any of you guys know what's the dropping rate and if they don't start dropping before Act/area X?

Thanks.

Comment: @fbueckert Technically, they are strictly different questions. The linked question is asking for blacksmithing plans while this one is asking for jeweller designs...

Comment: The qustion asks, "Where do recipes drop?" Jeweler plans are included in that, even if they aren't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: this question is much more specific - Personally, I'd like to know the answer to this specific qn.

Comment: @fcrick This question is not really much more specific, it just uses the word "Jeweler".  There are only two kinds of recipes, I don't really see the need to have a recipes question, and then a more specific jeweler recipe question - especially given that the answers will be the same.

Comment: @Anzurio Don't take the discussion the wrong way, it's a good question - I just feel it's already been asked.

Answer (score 1):

Earliest i got past 1.0.3 was act 2 inferno, it may be luck but friends also got them starting from this act.

Answer (score 1):

Rumor has it that the worm cave (random spawn in desolate sands act 2) drops recipes. One dropped for me there, when I heard someone mention it, sorta clicked. Unverified, but a lead.

Also had one drop in the Spirit zone (think thats what its called) the third portal in the arkives at the end of act 2.