# Where are the key wardens and where are my Infernal Machines to create a Hellfire Ring/Hellfire Amulet?

Tags: diablo-iii

In order to obtain a Hellfire Ring or Amulet, one has to work their way through the Uber Boss system of harvesting machines and organs to produce a legendary ring or amulet ([official blog post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7597724/New_Event_The_Infernal_Machine-10_15_2012)).

To create the infernal machine required to open the portals to the Ubers, the keys are drops from mobs nick named Key Wardens.

Where are the various key wardens?  Are there any requirements for making the machines drop? What's the drop rate on different difficulty settings?

Comment: @JQAn As long as you choose a quest that has a waypoint for the warden's location, it doesn't matter which one you choose.  If all you care about is farming keys, just always choose the last quest, to give yourself the maximum flexibility for earning NV.

Comment: @Tharius do you mind changing your accepted answer to the correct one

Comment: @Z Do you mind changing your accepted answer to the correct one via the edit button?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Reaper of Souls update has substantially modified this process from the launch version.

There are 4 different machines that can be created which correspond to the particular fights to obtain a particular organ.  No more opening 3 portals to guarantee seeing the uber you need.

The machines spawn directly from the Keywardens.  As of patch 2.3 each member of a party has an independent probability of generating a machine.

- Act 1: Fields of Misery:         Odeg      - [Infernal Machine of Bones](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-bones)
- Act 2: Dahlgur Oasis:            Sokahr    - [Infernal Machine of Gluttony](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-gluttony)
- Act 3: Stonefort:                Xah'Rith  - [Infernal Machine of War](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-war)
- Act 4: Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier: Nekarat   - [Infernal Machine of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-evil)

The Infernal Machine plan can drop from any of the Keywardens and they all have a small chance to spawn a second key that is not particular to them.

The [level 70 Hellfire Ring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/hellfire-ring) requires one of all four organs, the new crafting plan which costs 5,000,000 gold coins from Squirt in Act 2 and 50,000 coins to craft.

The organs are:

- [Vial of Putridness](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/vial-of-putridness) ([Infernal Machine of Gluttony](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-gluttony))
- [Leoric's Regret](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/leorics-regret)    ([Infernal Machine of Bones](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-bones))
- [Idol of Terror](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/idol-of-terror)     ([Infernal Machine of War](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-war))
- [Heart of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/heart-of-evil)      ([Infernal Machine of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/infernal-machine-of-evil))

It is still possible to obtain the original keys while you are level 60 and to craft the [level 60 Hellfire Ring](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/jeweler/recipe/hellfire-ring-of-strength) as per the legacy information that used to be contained in answers here (you can see that info from reviewing edits on the top answers).

It is not possible to stack the level 60 and 70 Hellfire Rings to obtain an 80% experience gain bonus.

The key rates are [reported to be](http://www.diablowiki.net/Torment#Infernal_Machine_Drop_Rates) but are [not universally accepted](http://d3resource.com/difficulties.png) as:

- Torment    I: 25%
- Torment   II: 28%
- Torment  III: 33%
- Torment   IV: 38%
- Torment    V: 43%
- Torment   VI: 50%
- Torment  VII: 60%
- Torment VIII: 70%
- Torment   IX: 80%
- Torment    X: 90%

The organ drop rates are [estimated to be](http://d3resource.com/difficulties.png):

- Torment    I: 100% * 1 organ roll
- Torment   II:  10% * 2 organ rolls
- Torment  III:  20% * 2 organ rolls
- Torment   IV:  30% * 2 organ rolls
- Torment    V:  40% * 2 organ rolls
- Torment   VI:  50% * 2 organ rolls
- Torment  VII: 100% * 2 organ rolls
- Torment VIII:  10% * 3 organ rolls
- Torment   IX:  25% * 3 organ rolls
- Torment    X:  50% * 3 organ rolls

Comment: Version 2.3 has removed Keys completely. Now Infernal machines drop directly from keywardens.

Answer (score 47):

This post has been updated for 2.0.1 to only contain the locations of the keywardens.

The updated drop rates can be found in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/157966/):

---

Key of Destruction

- Odeg the Keywarden is in Fields of Misery in act 1.  Odeg always spawns with the molten effect, and he has a big fireball spell that can do ok damage.  He also has the jail affix and likes to kite a lot, making it difficult to engage him as a melee character.

Key of Hate

- Sokahr the Keywarden spawns in Dahlgur Oasis. Dahlgur oasis is quite big and he can spawn anywhere in that zone, so having multiple people helps a lot.  Sokahr has an electric attack and a whirlwind attack.  When he starts whirlwinding, I recommend to back up since that attack hurts a lot.  He also has mortars.
- Another note here is that he is a cake walk for a demon hunter using the ball lightning attack.  Since he often (always?) appears with a slow missile shield these balls hang around sparking on him if you can stay far enough away that he isn't chasing you.  Alternately make him chase you in a circle so the balls stay within his shield.

Key of Terror

- Xah'Rith the Keywarden is in Stonefort.  Xah'Rith is the hardest of the 3 key wardens as he teleports around a lot and have a high damage aoe attack.  If you are a melee character, it helps a lot if you lure him to one of the many stair cases in the area so he can't run away as easily.

Infernal Machine Blacksmithing Plans

- Dropped from Nekarat the Keywarden in Act 4.  Has very high damage and aoe.  He also has a chance to drop any of the 3 keys.

Comment: You left out Sokahr's brutal mortar attack.  I think he is Vortex as well.  Quite a pain for ranged characters.

Comment: @bwarner well I'm a barb so I tend to ignore that stuff :D

Comment: I start the act two one on the assault on Belial because it gives you Leah and Adria, which not much but does help.

Comment: Another helpful hint is to get 3 sets of all 3 keys. That will guarantee that you'll unlock all 3 realms. Otherwise, you make get the same organ twice...

Comment: In order to craft the level 70 Infernal Machine, you also need a Key of Evil, which drops from Nekarat.

Comment: @Adeese: For that one you need completely different keys: Gluttony, Bones, War, and Evil.

Comment: @MooingDuck True, although they drop from the same bosses, just in a level 70 game.

Comment: From the 2.2.0 patch notes:
Nekarat the Keywarden has been moved from Silver Spire Level 1 to Gardens of Hope 2nd Tier.

Answer (score 17):

Lylirra made a [blue post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6712951823#16) about drop chances.  You have to have 5 stacks of Nephalim Valor and the drop chance scales up to 100% with monster power level.

> You'll need five stacks of NV in order for the keys and the demonic organ pieces to drop.
>
> Currently, both the keys and the demonic organ pieces (Vengeful Eye, Devil's Fang, and Writhing Spine) have higher chances to drop in higher MP levels, all the way up to 100% in MP10.

When they appear, they'll show us as legendary items, making them easy to distinguish from the other items the mobs may pop.

[Diablofans](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/71961-the-full-guide-to-obtaining-the-infernal-machine-important-information-on-monster-powers-blizzard-talks-ww-barbs-blizzard-on-energy-twister/) posted information on the location of all of the keys:

> - Key 1 - Found on Goat Mutant Key Warden in the Fields of Misery (Act 1)
> - Key 2 - Found on Dune Dervish Key Warden in Dahlgur Oasis (Act 2)
> - Key 3 - Found on Morlu Spellcaster Key Warden in Stonefort (Act 3)
> - Infernal Machine Plan - Found on Terror Demon Key Warden in Silver Spire Lvl 1 (Act 4)
> - The Key Wardens will always spawn in each Inferno game.

Comment: What is the optimal quest to start in each act for getting NV 5 just before finding the Wardens?

Comment: I typically start at the last quest in the Act, go to my preferred farming spot to get 5 stacks, then go to the area where the Key Warden is. If you are only concerned with keys, do the same thing but go straight to the correct area. Just go somewhere else for a bit if you don't have enough NV by the time you find the Warden.

Answer (score 13):

[As verified by a Blizzard employee](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11884298567?page=1#7), this is the up-to-date information about keys, in Patch 2.0.1:

1) You don't need to do anything special; just kill the Key Wardens

2) Keys only drop on Torment difficulty

3) Key drop rates:

- Torment I: 25%
- Torment II: 28%
- Torment III: 33%
- Torment IV: 38%
- Torment V: 43%
- Torment VI: 50%

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.0.1 and the remove of NV buff. Keys and others stuffs can drop at anytime.