# Where can I find the keys and the plans for the infernal machine?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the key wardens and where are my keys?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/where-are-the-key-wardens-and-where-are-my-keys)

What are the locations of the monsters that can drop the keys and the plans for the infernal machine introduced in patch 1.0.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Blizzard's article on the [Infernal Machine](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/7597724/New_Event_The_Infernal_Machine-10_15_2012):

> To craft the Infernal Machine, players will first need to collect four components from powerful Keywardens in each Act of Inferno:
>
> - The Key of Destruction will drop from Odeg the Keywarden in Act I - Fields of Misery
> - The Key of Hate will drop from Sokahr the Keywarden in Act II - Dahlgur Oasis
> - The Key of Terror will drop from Xah'Rith the Keywarden in Act III - Stonefort
> - The Blacksmithing Plans will drop from Nekarat the Keywarden in Act IV - Silver Spire Level 1

Note that these only drop in Torment.  The higher the level of Torment, the better the chance of getting one, up to 50% at Torment 6.

The plans are taught to your blacksmith, and only are needed *once*.  After that, you just need the keys from the previous three acts, as using the Infernal Machine consumes it.