# I just killed the first Key Warden and can't find key

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the key wardens and where are my keys?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/where-are-the-key-wardens-and-where-are-my-keys)

I just killed the first Key Warden in the Fields of Misery but do not see a key. He dropped all kinds of items but no key. Do you have to kill them without dying or within a certain amout of time in order to obtain a key?

Comment: The keywardens do not always drop keys.

Comment: If you are having trouble finding the answer in the linked question, you need to have five stacks of Nephalem Valor to have any chance of finding a key.  With five stacks, the chance of a key dropping ranges from 5% on Monster Power 0 to 100% on Monster Power 10.  See [What's the Expected Value of number of runs required for a hellfire ring?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120837/whats-the-expected-value-of-number-of-runs-required-for-a-hellfire-ring) for more discussion.