# Is the key warden part of a quest?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the key wardens and where are my keys?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/where-are-the-key-wardens-and-where-are-my-keys)

i recently started playing Diablo 3 and of course want to complete the Hellfire quest.

Is any of the key wardens part of a quest that is usually done in public games?

If it is not, what is the quest that starts closest to any of the key wardens?

Answer (score 1):

No, the key wardens are not part of any quest. As for where to find them refer to [the question Bora linked](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85978/where-are-the-key-wardens-and-where-are-my-keys). As long as the Waypoint that takes you to the proper area is available the quest you choose to play is not relevant.

Comment: which quests do the waypoints belong to? i might convince people to come with me.