# How much damage should an end-game barbarian do?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I've been playing several characters in Diablo 3, but my first and furthest along is [my barbarian](http://goo.gl/AV3pM).  Recently, a friend (monk) and I have started making [key-runs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/85978/14720) in order to craft the Hellfire Ring.  Although I don't die as often as he does (barely) playing at elevated monster power, he does a **ton** more damage than I do.  I'm doing around 27k damage.  After some googling around, it appears that I could get more damage out of this fella, but I can't find anything that actually shows a good average damage for a 60+ barbarian, just lots of "look at my barbarian he did 6-bajillion DPS against Azmodan" type posts.  Does anyone have any knowledge or resources for this?

Comment: You need more crit damage.  That's where the synergy with crit chance starts rocketing your DPS into the six digits.

Comment: 27k is fairly low for an end game barbarian.  To be able to solo or handle mp5 reasonably well, you should have at least 50k dps (not including battle fury or wotb).  This highly depends on how much available gold you have though.  I can't open your link at work so I can't make any gear suggestions for now.  As an example, my barb had ~200k fully buffed dps (~140k unbuffed) and was able to solo mp7.

Comment: @spartacus - holy bejeepers!  I'd love to see those specs.  I would have posted my stat pics here but don't want a mod to think the question is solely about my barbarian and close as too localized.

Comment: You should take a look at [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69523/building-barbarian-in-inferno).

Comment: @fbueckert - Yea, I saw that.  Do you think it's still pretty accurate even after patch 1.05?

Comment: @fbueckert that question/answer is slightly out of date.  Pretty much there are 2 main end game barb builds these days, the ww/tornado build and the frenzy/throw build.

Comment: @spartacus Yeah, it really should get an update.  I don't play Barbarians, though, so I can't do it.

Comment: its going to take too much writing to write up everything, but the first thing I see that you are lacking in is crit hit damage

Comment: some very specific gearing tips based on your stuff: Ditch sky splitter, find a high dps axe with a socket so you can put an emerald into it for crit hit damage.  Drop your gladiator gauntlets and get yourself a pair of cheap crit + attack speed gloves, preferably with res and/or stats.  Your DPS is a bit low currently for life steal to be that effective, so you need to bump it up to the 70k range at the minimum.  This is the usual build end game barbs run for a ww/tornado build: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/barbarian#ahPRUk!VYZ!YZcYZc

Comment: your life is also very low, i'd consider putting amethysts into the sockets instead of rubies.  I don't know how much gold you have to work with though.

Comment: @spartacus - excellent suggestions, thank you very much!  Too bad DiabloProgress is a little weighted toward gold buyers, it looked promising.

Comment: I threw together [a barb](http://www.diabloprogress.com/hero/shanrak-1253/Shanrak/13962158) yesterday for about a third of what I sold my last barb for, fully buffed can reach 200k dps(true dps of ~500k) and has 1m EHP.  Total cost was a shade under 200m none of the pieces cost more than 20m, which is pretty reasonable.  I was planning on snagging a cheap natalya reflection to go with the boots but couldn't find a cheap one, so I just kept the boots :P

Comment: general gearing tricks to save money: 1 vit = ~0.7 resist all = ~7 armor = ~7str when determining EHP, but 100 vit costs 1/3rd as much as 70 res all.  4.5 stats = 1% crit damage (saves a LOT of money for weapons).  My axe with 60% crit dam and a socket would easily cost 50+m where the same axe with 270 str (~60% crit dam) cost me 12m.  On top of that STR boosts armor, which is even nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [DiabloProgress](http://www.diabloprogress.com/rating.stat_dps_unbuffed/class.barbarian). You're asking for an end game barb, so compare to the world number 1.

The stats you should get:
Minimum 1000dps weapon with a socket.
Minimum of 2.3 attacks per second.
At least 45% critical hit chance.
Critical hit damage.
Around 2k strength.
8-10k armour.
600 AR

Comment: oh. and vitality too.

Comment: most of the top end players on diablo progress has spent billions of gold (and possibly hundreds of $$$) on their gear, I wouldn't use them as a measuring stick :P

Comment: he's asking end game gear, in case you didnt notice. keyword: end-game

Comment: hellfire costs at least 2 million for the recipe only. If he can afford hellfire, and can win uber bosses, he can afford to be at least 150k dps

Comment: 2m isn't a lot of gold, most of the gear on the top end of diablo-progress costs 500m+ for a *single piece*.  Hitting 100k dps should be fine and would cost maybe 30m-50m or so, which is fairly reasonable.

Comment: Hellfire runs require you to be around mp6-10 before you can actually get the drops. To actually even play those mp's with uber bosses, you're already talking about 50m per piece. The OP's question is regarding what should he strive for end game, not how to improve his gear a little. 

The stats I given him are possible to achieve within a 10mil budget for all your items if you camp on the AH long enough.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this as the answer.  Even though most of the high-ranking players on this site have absurd gear, it gives me a target.  Thanks again all for your insights.

Comment: I just started again D3 and i Had about 5M ,used only 3M to gear up and then killed Diablo MP5 With the proper build. As a WW/Tornado Barbarian if you master your build you dont need a lot of stuff just some Skill ;-)

Answer (score 4):

A solid benchmark for farming **MP10** in patch 1.0.8 with a spin-to-win barbarian is **170k unbuffed DPS with 650k EHP**.  You can use a tool like [d3up](http://d3up.com/) to help calculate these values and help determine the efficacy of potential item upgrades.

A more generally applicable rule of thumb for efficient xp/legendary farming is that you **should be able to kill trash mobs in 3-5 seconds and elites in under 45 seconds** while dieing to less than 1 in 5 elite packs.  Pick the monster power where this holds true for your character.  For ubers, you'll want to do the highest MP that you can successfully complete.

As far as improving your character's damage, my advice would be to move your focus away from legendary items and focus on stats alone.  [This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/lv?key=0AmD1dBDGqT7YdC1tYy00TmhRbGpsMElPS0V3ME9TZWc&toomany=true#gid=0) is a great list of what stats to look for in which slots.  You certainly won't be able to afford items with the values listed but you can use it to focus on the appropriate stats for each slot and get the most for your money.

For example, the amulet slot has great DPS potential (high crit chance and crit damage caps) while pants have great EHP potential (high AR and vit caps + slots).  In your case, your pants are more DPS focused while your amulet is more EHP focused.  If you were to swap the focus on these slots you could, fairly cheaply, increase both your DPS and EHP.

Comment: great post, agree with just about everything here.  Though i'd say you should also have 6% LS for mp10 (be it from gear or passives).  And I'd rather look at true DPS (d3up can calculate that for you) over the DPS listing on your char sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Stack crit chance and crit damage on most of your items.  You want a 1:10 ratio for crit chance to damage. For example, 45% crit chance =/= 450% crit damage.

Also, you should get a lot of vitality on your items.  Do not worry too much about strength, but try to get a 1:3 ratio for strength to vitality, as in 50 strength and 150 vitality.  My barb at level 60 with no paragon is around 250k dps unbuffed. Fully buffed with wob and br and punish rune in bash, I hover around 470-480k.