# Does the 'Splintered Oar' have a special purpose?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this item have a legend? Are there others like it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69712/why-does-this-item-have-a-legend-are-there-others-like-it)

Just got the Splintered Oar to drop in Act I on Hell. Is it just an Easter Egg that is meant to be funny, or is it like [Rakinishu's blade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67796/does-rakinishus-blade-have-a-special-purpose)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a unique 'magic' quality item. From the information available at the moment this just seems to be a flavour item with no other purpose in the game. (Falling under the 'Easter egg' category).

It's worth noting that during beta this item was [classified as a legendary item according to Gamona](http://diablo3.gamona.de/database/splintered-oar-two-handed-swords.html), but is still reported as a legendary item by other sites claiming to be up to date, such as [D3DB](http://d3db.com/item/i/splintered-oar).

This question is a duplicate of [*Why does this item have a legend? Are there others like it?*](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69712/why-does-this-item-have-a-legend-are-there-others-like-it/72389#72389)