# Bashiok nerfed my class. I want to kill him. Where do I find him?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

I have [the Blade.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67796/does-rakinishus-blade-have-a-special-purpose) I want the achievement. And besides, Bashiok is a smug jerk and killing him would be satisfying.

I know he's a rare spawn, but what kind of mob is he a variant on? In which chapters, zones, and difficulties can he spawn?

Comment: I miss you [tag:murder]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bashiok is a rare Fallen Shaman mob who can be randomly found (or not found) In Dalghur Oasis and the unique title: "Death is not the End".

[image]

If you're not satisfied after killing him in game, you can also [hunt him down on twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/Bashiok).