# Where can I find Rakanishu's blade, and where can I find Bashiok?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bashiok nerfed my class. I want to kill him. Where do I find him?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68008/bashiok-nerfed-my-class-i-want-to-kill-him-where-do-i-find-him)

There's an achievement which has you slay [a popular public spokesperson of Blizzard](http://www.diablowiki.net/Bashiok):

[image]

Where can I find Rakanishu's Blade, and where can I find Bashiok?

Answer (score 2):

Rakanishu's blade and Bashiok are both in the Dahlgur Oasis, As the Shrine of Rakanishu is an event that will give you the blade for completing it, granted it is not there everytime. I found it on my nightmare playthrough after looking desperately in my normal playthrough :(.

Bashiok on the other hand is just a rare spawn monster that wonders around the oasis. people have found him in normal, I just happened to find him in nightmare playthrough as well right in front of the Development Hell random dungeon :D

Answer (score 0):

Rakanishu's Blade is dropped after completing the Shrine of Rakanishu event in the Northern part of Dahlgur Oasis, northwest of the waypoint.

I haven't seen a definitive answer where Bashiok appears, I would assume him to be a random spawn.  There is speculation that he appears in Act II as a result of his reported levels.

Answer (score 0):

Rakanishu's Blade is acquired from the "Shrine of Rakanishu" event in Dahlgur Oasis.  After completing it you will receive Rakanishu's Blade (with a random set of enchantments/damage - doing this event multiple times will get you the blade with different stats).

I am unsure of where Bashiok is located, however.  He may be a random spawn.